# Round cart total for specific selected payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to round the final price at the checkout if someone chooses Cash on Delivery

The general idea of what I would like to achieve is:

```
    if payment_method == 'cod'{
    $cart_subtotal = round($cart_subtotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the cart totals will be re-calculated every time a user changes the payment method:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'trigger_checkout_refresh_on_payment_method_change');
function trigger_checkout_refresh_on_payment_method_change(){
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout').trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php
    endif;
}
```

There are many ways to round a price depending on what logic you want to achieve, but here's the most simple way to round the total if a user has chosen "Cash on delivery" as their payment method:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'round_total_for_specific_payment_methods', 10, 2 );
function round_total_for_specific_payment_methods( $total, $cart ) {
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    
    if ( $chosen_payment_method && $chosen_payment_method === 'cod' ) {
        $total = round( $total );
    }
    
    return $total;
}
```